# Why std::vector<int> contents are eliminated when passing them by value?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, parameter-passing, stdvector

I have an initialized std::vector of size 4 and I am trying to pass it to a function which must perform some sort of calculations on it and return the result.
By debugging I have noticed if I pass the vector by value, as soon as I enter the function the size of the vector becomes 0, whereas the capacity is correctly 4.
In order to understand which is the problem I have written an extremely simple code which has the same identical issue.

```
// @main.cpp
#include "fcn.h"
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vect;
    vect.push_back(0);
    vect.push_back(1);
    vect.push_back(2);
    vect.push_back(3);

    // As it should, at this point in the debugger vect.size() == 4
    printValues(vect);

    return 0;
}


// @fcn.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void printValues(vector<int> vect);


// @fcn.cpp
#include "fcn.h"
void printValues(vector<int> vect) {
    // As soon as I get here, vect.size() == 0
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) 
        std::cout << "vect[" << i << "] = " << vect[i] << endl;

}
```

I am pretty sure I have done this many times before and I have no idea why it is not working this time. The reason is probably trivial, but I cannot see it. The issue is "solved" only if I pass the vector by reference, but this seems utterly strange to me.

Last but not least, if I try to initialize `vect` with

```
vect = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

instead of `std::vector.push_back()` the debugger tells me that `vect` has a capacity 4 but size 0. Don't know if this can be of any relevance.

Comment: Maybe you are missing something in the posted code? Working for me.

Comment: you get the same behaviour also with this example? or only in the original? I didnt try, but I would be really surprised if there was something wrong with that code

Comment: I am compiling this exact code and it is not working.

Comment: When you say it isn't working, are you talking about what the debugger says, or how the code actually behaves? If it's what the debugger says, you likely have compiled a "Release" version instead of a "Debug" version. That is, you'll need to turn off optimizations and compile with debug symbols to get the debugger to give you the proper output.

Comment: [Doesn't reproduce](http://ideone.com/k2is2d). Nor [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GD3qqRhj8hO94PMj). Perhaps give your project a full rebuild.

Comment: "if I pass the vector by reference, but this seems utterly strange to me." Why? This is the standard practice and you are expected and encouraged to follow it. (Pass by const reference because you are not changing the vector in the function; pass by value if you need an actual copy separate from the original vector).

Comment: Well that was my first thought, but unfortunately I am already using the "Debug" version. By "not working" I mean both that the code doesn't behave properly and that using the debugger I see the strange behaviour I described in the question.

@n.m. As mentioned in the question, the code where I first found this problem is not the one I posted. I posted this simple code because it gives me the same problem and it is eliminates all the useless complexity of the original code.

Comment: It appears there's something wrong with the `std::vector` copy constructor on your platform. Check the integrity of your compiler and standard libraries.

Comment: Lets try and boil this down some more.  If you run [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe44a9c895ab1ab9) does it work?

Comment: @NathanOliver No it doesn't.
EDIT aside reinstalling VS14 what do you suggest?

Comment: OK.  There is something broken with your implementation then.  What are you using?

Comment: Generate output after preprocessing and check that there are no ugly macros that make this effect.

Comment: I am running Visual Studio 14 (2015) on Windows 10.

Comment: hmm.  I've used MSVS 2015 a lot without ever seeing this.  You might want to uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: Well, [this is VS2015](http://rextester.com/LLPN74891) and it works here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough rep to comment so I will post an answer.
The code you posted works for me but you should be aware that when you pass the std::vector as you show, a copy of the vector (along with contents) is created and passed to the printValues(..) function. Perhaps the copy is not working correctly on your system. By passing the std::vector as a reference, the original vector is passed to the function which should preserve all values and attributes of the std::vector 'vect'. I suggest the following change:

```
void printValues(std::vector<int> &vect);

void printValues(std::vector<int> &vect) {
//...
for (size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    std::cout << "vect[" << i << "] = " << vect[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Note: I made a few tweaks to get a clean compile on my system.

Comment: Yes you are right, that would work fine, but I would rather pass the vector by value and not by reference. I am now trying reinstalling Visual Studio hoping to solve the problem. I will post an answer if this solves the problem and I will comment here if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer because I managed to solve and I want to share how.

As many pointed out, there was absolutely no problem with the code I wrote, but rather there was something wrong with std::vector library. I solved by uninstalling VS14 and reinstalling it back again.

I have absolutely no idea why this happened since I don't even know where the STL files are stored.